# Map excel values by category

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016

I have a table containing main and secondary values for different documents (each document having its own id as a number which can have decimals).

From this source table, I want to obtain another one with a mapping between values and documents and for each mapping I want to see if the value is "main" or "secondary" for that document in the original table.

I already have the first two columns created in the mapping table, but I can't figure out what formula to use for the 3rd column.

So far I have tried XLOOKUP but it doesn't seem to work because some documents show up more than once in the original table.

Starting table:

[image: Starting table]

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Did you actually use `XLOOKUP()`? I mean, you tagged Excel-2010. One of which is not correct.

Comment: @JvdV I tagged it in case there is a formula or something out there that is useful and I didn't think of it that is not specific to Excel versions after 2010 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

[image]

Formula in `C8`:

```
=FILTER(A$1:B$1,BYCOL((A$2:B$4=A8)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&CHAR(10)&B8&",",","&CHAR(10)&C$2:C$4&","))),LAMBDA(a,SUM(a))))
```

Or, for older versions:

```
=INDEX(A$1:B$1,SUMPRODUCT((A$2:B$4=A8)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&CHAR(10)&B8&",",","&CHAR(10)&C$2:C$4&","))*COLUMN(A1:B1))))
```

Comment: for some reason this gives me a "#NAME?" error in my spreadsheet

Comment: Since you used `XLOOKUP()` I assumed you'd have acces to `FILTER()` and `BYCOL()` in ms365. Which version are you using since it's not Excel 2010.

Comment: I use Excel 2016. I modified the tag in the original question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then that's why you get the error. Also, you can't have used `XLOOKUP()` in that case since it was not available in that version of Excel. See if the edited answer works for you.